# Why can't static member functions be constant?

Tags: c++

I went through the already existing thread on this topic and wasn't convinced with the explanation.

What I could pick up from there was:

When a non-static member function is declared `const`, the restriction is imposed on this `this` pointer. As static member functions donot involve the `this` pointer, they cannot be declared `const`.

Is that it? Doesn't sound too convincing to me. I mean, I'm not questioning why it's so. I just want to to the reason why.

Comment: What would the `const` in a `const static` member function refer too? Opposed to the `const` in a non-static member function, that makes the `this`-pointer `cont`.

Comment: It would be meaningless. By the definition you've given, all static member functions are already `const`, since they don't mess with `this`.

Comment: @RoyShmuli That questions addresses static const instance variables. This one is about member functions.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: If it's not `const`, I could modify something inside the function and it would apply to all the instances of it. If it's `const`, I won't be able to modify it. Kinda like `static final` variables in Java (even though we are talking about functions, not variables here).

Comment: All instances of what? What kind of "something" are you talking about?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Obviously the data member variables.

Comment: I can modify the data members (instance variables) inside the non-const static function.

Comment: Wait, so a static member function cannot access the instance variables directly as the other non-static member functions can?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Cheers mate. Waiting for your answer. Really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Instance variables of what instance, Grendan?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Instance variables of...aah, I see your point. Thank you for helping me out here. I'm just a beginner. :)

Answer (score 4):

A `const` non-static member function is allowed to modify local, static, and global variables; it just isn't allowed to modify members of its class through the `this` pointer (implicitly or explicitly). A `const` static member function, therefore, would be allowed to modify local, static, and global variables, just like a non-member function. This would make the `const` meaningless.

If you want to write a function that isn't allowed to modify any non-local variables at all, you can declare it `constexpr`, although that also imposes additional restrictions.

Comment: Wait, so a static member function cannot access the instance variables directly as the other non-static member functions can?

Comment: @Grendan No of course not. Try doing it, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the const/non-const distinction for functions is important is that there are contexts in which it is not legal to call a non-const function. So the distinction can be used to enforce invariants.

For example, if you pass a non-const reference to a function, if your class is properly designed, you are guaranteed that the function can't change the value of the thing the reference refers to. This allows you to avoid copies.

Also, a non-const reference can't bind to a temporary. This permits functions to signal whether they return values through references or just take a value. You will get an error at compile time if you inadvertently ignore a returned value because a temporary was created unexpectedly.

None of this would apply to static functions because there is no context in which you would be prohibited from calling them. So the entire rationale for the distinction does not exist with static functions.